# Authenticate user before installing VsCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to Authenticate user when the user clicks the install button or when user tries to install a `vsix` file directly.

Is there a process to do this? Or setting?

Comment: It is an invalid requirement to authenticate users before installation. Both the extension and VSIX file can be easily reverse engineered, and you get no protection at all. You might get the option to write key functions in another language, wrap them up in TypeScript/JavaScript, and sell licenses, but that must happen after installation.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to hide or show extension in marketplace based on network or proxy?

Comment: I don't think Microsoft ever develops VSCode Marketplace with that feature. If you work for a company and want to block certain VSCode extensions, you might set up your own marketplace, and block Microsft's completely (possible but rather complex).

Comment: Ok, then is there a way to deactivate the extension from code after the user is found unauthenticated. 
I built a jar file which has the http callout logic and I am calling that from `activate` class, which is the class used for activating the plugin, how can I deactivate the plugin if the user is found unautheticated.

Comment: If the user is not authenticated, throw exceptions and refuse to work.